# why doesn't it run? jtable queries

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable gridview = new JTable(modelo);
conexiones.daofutbolista buscar = new conexiones.daofutbolista();

    public void llenartabla()
        {

            ResultSet datostraidos=buscar.buscarfutbolistas(); 
        try
        {
        while(datostraidos.next() ) 
        {
            Object [] fila = new Object[7]; // de 7 columnas


            for(int i=0;i<7;i++) // como son 7 columnas
            {

        fila[i]=datostraidos.getObject(i+1);
            }

            modelo.addRow(fila); 
            }

        }
        catch(Exception es)
        {
            System.out.println(es);
            }


            }
```

when i press  the button it not show them..

```
if(e.getsource()==btnMostrar)
{
llenartabla();
gridview.repaint();
gridview.revalidate();

}
```

it doesn't run, could you help me? thanks men!

this is my daoconnection

```
public ResultSet buscarfutbolistas()
 {
     ResultSet datos = null;
    String cadena="select * from futbolistas";
    try{
    Statement stm=conexion.getConnection().createStatement();

    datos=  stm.executeQuery(cadena);

return datos;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

        System.out.println(ex);

return datos;

    }


 }
```

Comment: Did you never understand that indentation-thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible causes:

- You forgot to add your KeyListener to the btnMostrar button.
- The ResultSet is empty, and will thus not run the body of the while-block.

Also, you need to reassign the model:

> gridview.setModel(modelo);

Try adding a print statement to isolate the error - they are your friends when debugging stuff like this :)

Comment: i dont get a bug, i did add actionlistener, i had 2 dates in the table

Comment: i had seen it now with "system.out.println("for")" and System.out.println("while"); and it does enter..

Comment: i got it 
conexion exitosa
for
for
for
for
for
for
for
while
for
for
for
for
for
for
for
while
 becase i got two dates

Comment: Can you show us your other swing objects, and how they relate to your table?

Comment: After the while-loop, try to set the model of the jtable again: gridview.setModel(modelo);

Comment: of course but what object do you need see? in the code is DefaultTable and Jtable, what  do you want to see friend?

Comment: mmm well do you believe i have a problem in my daoconnection? this is my method in class daofutbolista\n

Comment: If you do get a print-statement in the while-loop, it fetches the data fine. I think I would try to create a new DefaultTableModel after the while-loop and add it to your model, to see if it works!

Comment: i had solved it.. this needs model.addColumn("id");   modeladdColum.("other column");

Comment: Ahh of course, you need the columns. Consider implementing your own AbstractTableModel, to avoid this problem again.

Comment: LOL well thank you very much much FREDERIK WORDENKJOLD THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: no problem, I'm glad I could keep you company while you solved it yourself ;)